Toilet won't stop flushing, flush valve stuck open
The pictured toilet flush valve has stopped working with the valve stuck open, so that the water just flows into the toilet without filling the cistern. Pressing or jiggling the flush buttons doesn't fix it.
How might I remove the valve mechanism to try to better understand the fault or replace the mechanism?
It was installed in 2011, in case that matters.



no wonder, it is pretty dirty, clean it

@DIY75, thanks, I think, but the parts that are most dirty aren't the ones giving the problem. At this point I don't know how to remove the flush mechanism to clean it.

Find a maker/model name on it, research installation instructions, follow them in reverse.

Your valve resembles a Caroma Novelli like this one. and probably uses similar installation procedures.

amazing how teknology has improved on the toilet to make it so much better than that easily removable and replaceable $5 flapper valve that worked for so many years.  [might be a boeing design there]
anyway, I don't know that make/model toilet, and you did not say.
How might I remove the valve mechanism? ... you unscrew it from the tank; and from the looks of it you might have to remove the tank.
It sticks open because minerals in the water corrode and/or build up on the [plastic] internals of that... which you can't get to given it's awesomely futuristic design.
replace your fill as well with either a cheap universal or a korky quiet fill (and maybe opt for the long life/platinum/whatever better for hard water model korky)
The fill you can almost always replace with something off the depot/lowes shelf for $10; the flush mechanism in the center depends on the toilet.
something to consider: don't buy a toilet without first knowing whether you can [easily] get and replace the flush mechanism, or at the very least know what that will cost and where to get it from.

With this specific flush valve, the roughly-circular middle part can be rotated (making a clicking sound) until a tab is lined up with a hole so that part of the mechanism can be removed. The following picture shows the part to hold on to and turn, and the lower arrows indicate the parts that needed to line up to remove the mechanism.

Once the mechanism was undone, I could see a semi-opaque plastic ring and a soft (silicone?) washer with a attachment in the centre that were both (separately) loose, with the washer under the plastic ring. The washer with the attachment in the centre was clearly meant to attach to a shaft that lifts when the flush button is pressed. It wouldn't click back into place, but a little blu-tak was enough to make the parts fit tightly again and get it working again temporarily. When that fails, I can glue it. When I do that I'll try to get a better photo in case it's of help to others.
